# PATH Formula not available

Tags: path, powerbi, dax, hierarchy

I'm trying to replicate the example at the bottom of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/path-function-dax where the PATH function returns a hierarchy of employees and who they report to.

When I go to create the calculated column and enter the DAX formula, the PATH function doesn't seem to be available when I start typing it out.

Copying the formula directly and adjusting the field names doesn't work either. It returns the following error: `Expression.Error: The name 'PATH' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.`

The data I'm using is just loaded directly from an Excel sheet so I don't think it's an issue with DirectQuery?

Comment: You're not mistakingly trying to enter that Calculated Column within Power Query, by any chance? Power Query Calculated Columns use a different language (M) to DAX.

Comment: I agree with Jos, this looks more like a Power Query error message than a DAX one.

Comment: I really with PQ had PATH functions :(

Comment: Doh! Thanks all, still very much a newbie to PowerBI